# How to show specific div's from li-objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I' trying to create a `<ul>` with `<li>` objects to slide the UL away and show specific div's. 
I have these div-tags:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
```

And this list:

```
<ul class="meny">
   <li id="show1">Show 1</li>
   <li id="show2">Show 2</li>
   <li id="show3">Show 3</li>
</ul>
```

Why doesn't this JS work?

```
$(function() {
   $("#show1").click(function() {
       $(".meny" ).toggle("slide");
       $("#1").click("show");
   });
});
```

I've been trying all night long...

**EDIT**

I'm trying to get my project to have a CLICK-event fired when you press a specific list object. When that is done, the whole ul should slide away and show a specified div.

See: http://aatw.se/test/booking.html

Comment: people are answering, but is it what you want? because it's not very clear to me what you are wanting to happen.

Comment: This piece of code does not make any sense to me. Once you click on `show1`, you would never have access to it again. What are you trying to get to ?

Comment: I've posted a example here, http://aatw.se/test/booking.html Just click "Logga in" and pass the alert. I want to click my LI's to slide away the meny and then show a hidden div.

Comment: i think you want hide and show div on  click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned, you need to call the show function. Your divs being empty is not an issue. But you should hide them on page load, or set them display to none in your css.

here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/D6qUe/2

here's your updated code

```
$("#show1").click(function() {
   $(".meny" ).toggle("slide");
   $("#1").show();
});

$('div').click(function(){
    $('.meny').toggle('slide');
    $(this).hide();    
});
```

possible css

```
div{width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#afa;border:1px solid #0f0;display:none;}
```

Comment: I tried this: 
`$("#showRule").click(function() {
   $("#meny" ).toggle("slide");
   $("#rules").show();
});` but it won't respond to my clicks on the li-object...

Comment: change $('#meny') to $('.meny') or to $('.meny li') to select the list items themselves.

Answer (score 5):

it should work too-

```
$("#1").css("display","block");
```

Answer (score 3):

`$("#1").click("show");`

should be:

```
$("#1").show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your `div's` are empty .

Next

```
 $("#1").click("show");
```

Supposed to be

```
 $("#1").show();
```

You can write up a single event handler to all the `li's` by using **HTML-5 data attributes**

**HTML**

```
<div id="1">This is Div 1</div>
<div id="2">This is Div 2</div>
<div id="3">This is Div 3</div>

<ul class="meny">
   <li data-id="1">Show 1</li>
   <li data-id="2">Show 2</li>
   <li data-id="3">Show 3</li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
   $("li").click(function() {
       $(".meny" ).toggle("slide");
       $("#" + $(this).data('id')).show();
   });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPgUu/632/)**